# Adding colour changing label backgrounds based on output value

Tags: python, tkinter, colors, label

I have tried everything I can think of to try and add colour changing label backgrounds depending on the cell output voltage. I am fairly new to Python and apologies if this seems silly.

I feel like I am missing something fundamental, as I am self taught I was hoping it might be something glaringly obvious I am doing wrong.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.ttk import Label
import time
import board
from adafruit_ina219 import ADCResolution, BusVoltageRange, INA219

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Equipmake Cell Voltage Tester')
root.geometry('800x450+0+0')
root.resizable(False, False)
root.attributes('-topmost', 1)
#root.iconbitmap('./assets/Equipmake.ico')

i2c_bus = board.I2C()

ina1 = INA219(i2c_bus,addr=0x40)
ina2 = INA219(i2c_bus,addr=0x41)
ina3 = INA219(i2c_bus,addr=0x42)
ina4 = INA219(i2c_bus,addr=0x43)

ina1.bus_adc_resolution = ADCResolution.ADCRES_12BIT_32S
ina1.shunt_adc_resolution = ADCResolution.ADCRES_12BIT_32S
ina1.bus_voltage_range = BusVoltageRange.RANGE_16V

ina2.bus_adc_resolution = ADCResolution.ADCRES_12BIT_32S
ina2.shunt_adc_resolution = ADCResolution.ADCRES_12BIT_32S
ina2.bus_voltage_range = BusVoltageRange.RANGE_16V

ina3.bus_adc_resolution = ADCResolution.ADCRES_12BIT_32S
ina3.shunt_adc_resolution = ADCResolution.ADCRES_12BIT_32S
ina3.bus_voltage_range = BusVoltageRange.RANGE_16V

ina4.bus_adc_resolution = ADCResolution.ADCRES_12BIT_32S
ina4.shunt_adc_resolution = ADCResolution.ADCRES_12BIT_32S
ina4.bus_voltage_range = BusVoltageRange.RANGE_16V

message = tk.Label(root, text="Press firmly against the cell then press Read Cells",
                   bg='blue',
                   fg='white',
                   font=('Helvetica', 20)
                   )

message.place(x=700, y=20, width=600, anchor='ne')

#print("ina219 test")

# measure and display loop
def button_clicked():
    bus_voltage1 = ina1.bus_voltage        # voltage on V- (load side)
    shunt_voltage1 = ina1.shunt_voltage    # voltage between V+ and V- across the shunt
    power1 = ina1.power
    current1 = ina1.current                # current in mA

    bus_voltage2 = ina2.bus_voltage        # voltage on V- (load side)
    shunt_voltage2 = ina2.shunt_voltage    # voltage between V+ and V- across the shunt
    power2 = ina2.power
    current2 = ina2.current                # current in mA
    
    bus_voltage3 = ina3.bus_voltage        # voltage on V- (load side)
    shunt_voltage3 = ina3.shunt_voltage    # voltage between V+ and V- across the shunt
    power3 = ina3.power
    current3 = ina3.current                # current in mA
    
    bus_voltage4 = ina4.bus_voltage        # voltage on V- (load side)
    shunt_voltage4 = ina4.shunt_voltage    # voltage between V+ and V- across the shunt
    power4 = ina4.power
    current4 = ina4.current                # current in mA
    
    # INA219 measure bus voltage on the load side. So PSU voltage = bus_voltage + shunt_voltage
    Cell1 = ("{:6.3f}V".format((bus_voltage1 + shunt_voltage1)))
    Cell2 = ("{:6.3f}V".format((bus_voltage2 + shunt_voltage2)))
    Cell3 = ("{:6.3f}V".format((bus_voltage3 + shunt_voltage3)))
    Cell4 = ("{:6.3f}V".format((bus_voltage4 + shunt_voltage4)))
    
    label1 = Label(
        root,
        text=str(Cell1),
        font=("Helvetica", 16))
    
    label1.place(x=190, y=110, width=150, height=100)
    
    label2 = Label(
        root,
        text=str(Cell2),
        font=("Helvetica", 16))
    
    label2.place(x=460, y=110, width=150, height=100)
    
    label3 = Label(
        root,
        text=str(Cell3),
        font=("Helvetica", 16))
    
    label3.place(x=190, y=270, width=150, height=100)
    
    label4 = Label(
        root,
        text=str(Cell4),
        font=("Helvetica", 16))
    
    label4.place(x=460, y=270, width=150, height=100)
    
    #print(str(Cell1))
    #print(str(Cell2))
    #print(str(Cell3))
    #print(str(Cell4))
    #print("")
    
button1 = tk.Button(root, text='Read Cells',
                    command=button_clicked,
                    bg='red',
                    fg='white',
                    activebackground='red',
                    font=('Helvetica', 16)
                    )

button1.place(relx=1.0, rely=0.5, width=120, height=300, anchor='e')

button2 = tk.Button(root, text='Read Cells',
                    command=button_clicked,
                    bg='red',
                    fg='white',
                    activebackground='red',
                    font=('Helvetica', 16)
                    )

button2.place(relx=0.0, rely=0.5, width=120, height=300, anchor='w')

root.mainloop()
```

This code works as a voltage tester I would just like to add the conditional colours, which has had me stumped for a day now.

Comment: What exactly have you tried that isn't working? Please provide a [mre] (MRE).

Comment: which label you want to change it's color's background ?

Comment: Hi Thanks for replying, I am trying to change the backgroung of the labels displaying the sell voltages `label1 = Label(
        root,
        text=str(Cell1),
        font=("Helvetica", 16))
    
    label1.place(x=190, y=110, width=150, height=100)
    
    label2 = Label(
        root,
        text=str(Cell2),
        font=("Helvetica", 16))
    
    label2.place(x=460, y=110, width=150, height=100)` etc, I tried creating an IF statement in the measure and display function and then a seperate function containing an if statment but i couldn't figure out how to make it work

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to define your labels outside of your function and then place them inside the function. From what I understand you are clicking a button to change the value. You could then check after the value change (in that function you call) if your label color has to change. If the condition is met, you just put a:

```
your_label_name.configure(bg="your_new_color")
```

I also recommend you to create variables for those colors and then just put them in the change.

Comment: Tomerikoo thanks for editing my answer, can you let me know how to enter code?